# Zend Framework Filter, prevent sql injection

Tags: zend-framework, sql-injection

For some important reasons I can't use standard methods provided by ZF to prevent sql injection. I have just wrote that (and I am using it on each POST/GET data from user):

```
$filter = new Zend_Filter_PregReplace();
$filter->setMatchPattern(array("/[';`]/"))
       ->setReplacement(array(''));
```

I am using MySQL database only. Is it enough? Is it secure now?

Comment: What are the important reasons?

Comment: I can't use Zend_Dd_Table or Zend_Select or direct mysql connection because data is added into database inside model's object using Zend_Db_Table_Abstract (and it's not good idea to change it). Not bad idea is to use Zend_Db quote() method but it adds ` on start end end (and it is not acceptable). I am looking for simpliest / fastest to implement solution. The best solution is equivalent for mysql_real_escape_string() in Zend Framework, but I can't find it.

Comment: Can't see your point :) You don't need to escape it twice. You can escape inside model, can't you?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Zend_Db::quote does use mysql_real_escape_string - this is what you should be using, not filters or regular expressions!

Answer (score 5):

Never do stuff like this using regular expressions. If you can't use Zend's database methods, use whatever sanitation the database library offers you. For mySQL's procedural wrapper, it would be [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string). For PDO, parametrized queries will take care of it automatically. And so on.

That said, I really don't understand why this is necessary in the first place. Why can't you use what the Framework offers? I bet there is a better workaround than doing sanitation on your own.

Answer (score 1):

You really *should* use sanitization provided by the framework - Zend (PDO, ORM). If you don't there is probably something already going wrong.

There are so many cases to inject malicious code, that to exclude all of them, you will have to find/roll your own some kind of framework to be safe.